# Use SVG rect as lightbox with cutout for the whole page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am currently trying to use an SVG to highlight a certain element on a page. For that I use an SVG `rect` as overlay and a mask as cutout.

Now my problem starts with scrolling, the SVG `rect` is only drawn in the current viewport. When scrolling down the overlay is not shown.

I can't use `position: fixed` as the cutout would also scroll. For structural reasons on our system I can't use a simple div solution. After resizing the browser window it is drawn the whole length.

Is it possible to force the `svg` to be drawn for the whole page height?

```css
.looong {
  height: 3000px;
}
#cutout {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999997;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index: 9999997;
}
```

```html
<div class="looong">
  Some Text, Big div
</div>
<svg id="overlay">
 <defs>
  <mask id="overlay-mask">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
   <rect id="cutout" x="100" y="200" width="100" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
  </mask>
 </defs>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.6" mask="url(#overlay-mask)" ></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

An absolutely positioned box is placed in respect to its nearest positioned container. If a positioned ancestor does not exist the box is instead positioned relative to the "initial containing block".

The "initial containing block" has the dimensions of the viewport so `height: 100%;` on `#outer` is therefore equal to the height of the viewport.

*For more information on the initial containing block see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#containing-block-details.*

## The solution

You can achieve the desired result with the following changes:

- Add a `html` selector with the style `position: relative;`. This will position `#overlay` relatively to it making its `height: 100%;` fill the full height of the `html` element

```css
html {
  position: relative;
}
.looong {
  height: 3000px;
}
#cutout {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999997;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999997;
}
```

```html
<div class="looong">
  Some Text, Big div
</div>
<svg id="overlay">
 <defs>
  <mask id="overlay-mask">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
   <rect id="cutout" x="100" y="200" width="100" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
  </mask>
 </defs>
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.6" mask="url(#overlay-mask)" ></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charme. Doesn't `body` also work for this?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. You can use `body` if you suppress the default `margin` that browsers apply, otherwise you end up with a white outline around the outside. https://jsfiddle.net/1g0da25y/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.full-body{
  position: relative;
margin: -10px;
}
.looong {
  height: 3000px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#cutout {
 box-sizing: content-box;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9999997;
 background-color: #FFF;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 border-radius: 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

#overlay {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index: 9999997;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-body">
<div class="looong">
Some Text, Big div
</div>
<svg id="overlay">
  <defs>
   <mask id="overlay-mask">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
    <rect id="cutout" x="100" y="200" width="100" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
   </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.6" mask="url(#overlay-mask)" ></rect>
 </svg>
  </div>
```